# Simple problem with dicT in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this dicT in my code that contain some positions.

```
position = ['712,352', 
            '712,390', 
            '622,522']
```

when I'm trying to run this part

```
def MouseMove(x,y):
    ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos(x,y)
```

with MouseMove(position[0]), the compiler says to me that I need 2 arguments on this command...
how can I solve this?

Comment: position is a list, not a dictionary.

Comment: Also, it's dict, not dic. I feel like a dick for pointing that out, but it might save you some unfortunate misunderstandings. :)

Comment: -1: It's not a dictionary in the first place.  The question makes no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a dictionary but a list.  Perhaps you mean to do something like this:

```
position = [(712,352), 
            (712,390), 
            (622,522)]

MouseMove(*position[0])
```

Comment: That's still one argument.  You want MouseMove(*position[0])

Comment: @Shady: it takes the item `position[0]` as a sequence and uses it as arguments to the function call.  `position[0]` was a tuple of two ints so it effectively called `MouseMove()` with those two as arguments.

Comment: @Shady: It's probably how I would have coded it myself (if that means anything).  I wouldn't know if it's the best but it is certainly fine in my eyes.